# What is slowing down my computer during gaming?

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, monitoring, gaming, performance-monitor

I have a Dell Latitude E6410 with Nvidia Quadro NVS 3100M and Windows 10 installed.

I've been regulary playing Counter Strike Source for past 1 year without a problem. But for past month or so, approx. 5 minutes after I start playing, it slows down do an uplayable level for approx. 2 minutes.

It hapens even when I first restart the computer and then shut down all uncecessary services and programs (like Google Drive sync, Slack, Spotify, etc.).

It happens in both original and unoriginal (non steam) versions of CS:S.

I tried to minimize the game during this slowdown to look in Task Manager, but many processes had a small CPU loads and together, they loaded CPU for 50+ %.

I'd like to find out what process causes this.

Do you know what could be the potencial issue or how to find out? I'd like to use some kind of performance logger that would log processes and their CPU loads during 15 minutes when I play.

Thank you!

Comment: How does your RAM and disk usage look like during gameplay? You can also use internal tools like the Resource Monitor or Performance Monitor from windows to log your system activity.

Comment: Please take a look at the temperatures of both CPU and GPU as those are likely high and could cause thermal throttling.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this will be helpful but i have some solutions i use when playing games like that.

1. make sure your using Gaming Power Plan. you can do this by going to your battery icon in your toolbar. Then selecting More Power Options. Then you have all of your options. If you don't have the Gaming Plan you can select High Performance.
2. Im pretty sure you all ready did this but make sure everything is on low or off. There should also be a option were it asks you if you want to use all cores.

3.if you have steam go to your library right click the game thats laggy and press property. Then go to Set Launch options and type "-noborder -novid" you can find more launch options on the internet.
dont worry though im pretty sure theres more solutions out there.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now I started to be a bit suspicious that my laptop is overheating, which leads to reduced CPU/GPU clock. When the heat is in normal levels, clocks are back on maximums and again, it takes a couple of minutes to heat my laptop again.